# Why does execvp() failed when executing more than 1 command in C?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, system

I'm writing a program that will read a list of commands from a file name cmdfile.txt and execute them in the terminal.

cmdfile.txt contain:

```
whoami
cal 4 2020
echo The time is:
date
```

I'm facing the issue that when the file only contain 1 single command line, the program works correctly. However, when the file contain more than 1 command lines, the command failed to execute or produce unknown command.
Below is my working code in progress:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include  <stdbool.h>
#include  <string.h>

void parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
     while (*line != '\0') {       /* if not the end of line ....... */ 
          while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
               *line++ = '\0';     /* replace white spaces with 0    */
          *argv++ = line;          /* save the argument position     */
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && 
                 *line != '\t' && *line != '\n') 
               line++;             /* skip the argument until ...    */
     }
     *argv = '\0';                 /* mark the end of argument list  */
}

void execute(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;
     pid = fork();
     if (pid < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
          perror("The error for fork() is: ");
          exit(1);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
               perror("The error is: ");
               exit(1);
          }
     }
     else {                                  /* for the parent:      */
          while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
               ;
     }
}

void  main(void)
{
     char  line[1024];             /* the input line                 */
     char  *argv[64];              /* the command line argument      */
     bool running = 1;

     FILE *fp = fopen("cmdfile.txt", "r");
     if(fp == NULL)
     {
          perror("Unable to open file!");
          exit(1);
     }

     while (fgets(line, 1024, fp)) {                   /* repeat until done ....         */      
          strtok(line, "\n");
          parse(line, argv);       
          execute(argv);
     }
}
```

My first guess is because of fgets didn't behave as I expected due to the separation of new lines? I have tried to print the line out to terminal to trace the error but I don't know what's wrong with the program. Can anyone please help me to point out the error I made?

My output when running the above code:

```
The error is: : No such file or directory
cal: not a valid year 2020
The time is:
The error is: : No such file or directory
The time is:
The error is: : No such file or directory
The error is: : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you please give the exact output you are getting? FWIW I ran that exact code with that exact input and it worked fine for me. Also, call `perror` if/when `execvp` fails to get a more specific error message.

Comment: How have you debugged the argument lists to `execvp()`?  You don't show a function to print them.  You don't report on the error, either (information in `errno`).  Error messages should be printed to `stderr`, too.

Comment: Hi, I have update the error I'm getting, can you have a look?

Comment: That can't be your exact output (or the code shown is not what you are actually running). The output shown does not match the print statements in the code. Please be precise. Show exact code with exact output.

Comment: Note that using `*argv = '\0';` to mark the end of the argument list is a very unconventional way of writing `NULL`.  The implication is that you are putting a null byte there, but in actuality, you are writing a null pointer.  Don't get me wrong: `'\0'` is an integer (not character) constant for zero, and zero will be converted to a null pointer.  But — you will confuse people reading your code.

Comment: Hi @kaylum, can you explain what I need to show? Because this is the code I'm currently working on, I'm a bit new to C

Comment: `printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");` and `Execvp failed!!` Can you explain why those don't match up? And how about calling `perror` and showing the debug output of the parsed command line?

Comment: Note that there is no need to test the return value of any of the `exec*()` family of functions.  If the function succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, if failed.  There's no particular harm in the test beyond the fact that it suggests that you're not aware of the semantics of the `exec*()` functions.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code using perror and updated the output, can you have a look?

Comment: Does `cmdfile.txt` come from a Windows machine and have CRLF line endings?  That could account for your problems.  Printing the arguments in `argv` carefully would help diagnose that.  For example: `char **ap = argv; while (*ap != NULL) printf("Arg: [[%s]]\n", *ap++);` would show `]]` at the start of the line if the lines end CRLF.

Comment: How about the debug print to show the contents of `argv` after parsing?

Comment: Yes it does come from a windows machine, can you show me how to fix it?

Comment: Use `strtok(line, "\n\r");` to fix the trouble.  That removes `\r` or `\n` at the end.  (It also removes `\r` in the middle of a line, but that's rarely a problem.). Looking for either "\r\n" or "\n" at the end is fiddlier.

Comment: It actually works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmdfile.txt` file comes from a Windows machine and was copied to a Linux machine without translating the line endings.  Therefore, each line ends with CRLF — `"\r\n"`.  Your code carefully zaps the `'\n'` with a null byte, but that leaves the `'\r'` in the string.  When you pass `"whoami\r"` to `execvp()`, it cannot find the command; it would find `"whoami"` but not the other.  It seems that `cal` doesn't like numbers that end with `\r` either.  And so on.  (The `echo` command isn't fussed about the `'\r'`.)

There are many ways to fix it.  In the context of your code, the simplest is to change the `strtok()` line in the loop in `main()` to read:

```
strtok(line, "\r\n");
```

The sequence of the characters in the string doesn't matter.